# PyTest ignoring -q modifier

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

im trying to run pytest from code as is stated here https://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code
but pytest is still spitting the output as it have not `-q` modifier even doing it from the console(like the example below)

```
py.test
    ============================= test session starts =============================
    platform win32 -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-2.8.5, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
    rootdir: C:\Users\A2eEngineer1\Desktop, inifile:
    collected 2 items

    test_range.py .F

    ================================== FAILURES ===================================
    ________________________ TestGettersSetters.test_fail _________________________

    self = <test_range.TestGettersSetters instance at 0x03257B48>

        def test_fail(self):
    >       assert (self.i != 42)
    E       assert 42 != 42
    E        +  where 42 = <test_range.TestGettersSetters instance at 0x03257B48>.i

    test_range.py:9: AssertionError
    ===================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.05 seconds ======================
```

-

```
py.test -q
    .F
    ================================== FAILURES ===================================
    ________________________ TestGettersSetters.test_fail _________________________

    self = <test_range.TestGettersSetters instance at 0x0334E6C0>

        def test_fail(self):
    >       assert (self.i != 42)
    E       assert 42 != 42
    E        +  where 42 = <test_range.TestGettersSetters instance at 0x0334E6C0>.i

    test_range.py:9: AssertionError
    1 failed, 1 passed in 0.03 seconds
```

-

```
py.test -qqq
    .F
    ================================== FAILURES ===================================
    ________________________ TestGettersSetters.test_fail _________________________

    self = <test_range.TestGettersSetters instance at 0x031CE6C0>

        def test_fail(self):
    >       assert (self.i != 42)
    E       assert 42 != 42
    E        +  where 42 = <test_range.TestGettersSetters instance at 0x031CE6C0>.i

    test_range.py:9: AssertionError
```

as the output shows, all of them are equals (except from the header in the first one) but on the documentation (the same link as above) it show that pytest should not produce output (whit `-qq`)
so. is this the intended behavior, is this a bug or im doing something wrong?

Comment: Why would you *want* to be able to suppress failing test reports?

Comment: i writting it to a file, so i just want to show how many passed/failed an have the details on the file, also it does not work as the examples on the documentation say